# How can I search Windows 10, excluding folders yet including zips?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, search, windows-search

I use a search string to generate statistics of documents processed, I used to use the -kind:folder but then realized it was blocking .zip files. Here are my requirements:

YES include .zip files in search results
YES include subfolder contents in search results
NO do not include .zip contents in search results

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In **Explorer** Search?

When I use **`Kind:folder`** in the Search box, .zip files, Libraries, Saved Searches, and shortcuts to folders were returned along with file system folders:
[image]

To limit results to only file folders, use
**`Type:directory`**
[image]

To limit results to only .zip files, use
**`Type:compressed`**
[image]

So, to return only file system folders and compressed folders, use:
**`Type:(directory OR compressed)`**  (Boolean operatoris in Search must be all caps)
[image]

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be getting me closer.  

Is there any way to list all files within subfolders, but not files within zips, yet still show zips as single files in the search results?  

We are using .zip in place of PDF to combine documents together, I need a count of all zips, plus the count of all files within subfolders (but not within zips).  
  
Thanks

Comment: In Windows Search, Advanced setup, do not index *contents* of Zip files; you'll have to rebuild the Index. (Also, you might need to turn off Windows handling of Zips (and CABs): https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-windows-built-in-zip . )

Comment: I ended up turning off search within zip files and used the grouping method from Keith's screenshot and I think it's going to work for me. Thanks for the help!